# Android Studio can not select a form factor for new project

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling

Today I wanted to create a new project. After given the name and click to next I was not able to to finish the next screen - see here:
[image]

AS is hanging and I have to kill the application and restart it. But after that the problem still remains. Until now I was not able to find a solution for that.

Comment: No one is forcing you to use Android Studio (or even the Gradle version it provides). Personally, I use Intellij and install Gradle on my own

Comment: It sounds like your computer is struggling with memory issues. Try adding more RAM

Comment: Lookiung to the task manager when running AS it seems to be fine. And of course is nobody forcing me to use AS. But it should be allowed to talk about frustration. And may be it helps that someone will do something. Actually, I found AS a very good application.

Comment: Maybe a network issue. I used Shadowsocks socks5 proxy in AS Settings - Appearance & Behavior - System Setting - HTTP proxy. After I updated to AS 3.1.3, it failed to "select a form factor for new project" and "Check connection". Then I select HTTP.on the SOCKS5 proxy, result in an unexpected “Check connection OK”, "New Project" works again.

Comment: You may check your network. I can't reach google so I use a Shadowsocks proxy usually. When AS saying "Loading stats…" "At least one form factor must be selected", the "Settings - Appearance & Behavior - System Settings - HTTP Proxy - Check connection" to "http://www.google.com" fails too. After switching "SOCKS" to "HTTP" in "Manual proxy configuration", the "Check connection" succeed. And the new project wizard goes on.

Comment: @ArthurMeier have you found a solution, I have the same issue.

Comment: @OM Infowave Developers: No not really. It became better after the newest update. But there are always some other issues. I guess one really has to have very good knowledge not only about Android but also with AS.